# VSTO Outlook Plugin Drag Drop issue

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

While debugging vsto extension with visual studio 2019, I cannot drag & drop files onto email area. This never happens while starting outlook by itself. There is no setting in visual studio project settings. This one is being shown on outlook (before releasing mouse button). How to pass this?
[image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely that means VS is running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator) and Windows Explorer is not.

Don't run VS as admin or run the Explorer as an admin as well.